# make jquery function available only when the page is ready

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to make a function available after the DOM is ready only? For example something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function open(obj)
{

}
});

<a href="#" onclick="open(this);">test</a>
```

If I do that clicking on `a` doesn't do anything at all, and if I have the function without the `document.ready`, when user clicks on the link while the page is loading, it doesn't display properly.

Thank you

Comment: what do you want it to display and your function doesnt have anything in it what do you want it to do??

Comment: The trouble with only having the function available when the DOM is ready is that there will be errors if he/she tries to click early. You'll probably want a global noop function, then overwrite it after DOM ready. `window.open = $.noop; $(document).ready(function(){ window.open = function(){...}...`

Comment: ...er, changing the global collision mentioned below as well.

Comment: it's actually openLightbox, I just wrote the question like that, thanks! :)

Comment: I think the inline event handler should be avoided in general.

Comment: I don't mind inline handlers at all. They solve some issues very simply and easily.

Comment: Content and markup (HTML) should be seperated from behaviour (JavaScript). This makes the code easier maintainable in the future. But in the end it's a bit of a matter of personal style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think open is reserved, but this works for me:

```
window.open2 = $.noop; // Deal with pre DOM-ready clicks

$(document).ready(function(){

window.open2 = function(obj)
{
    alert('test');
}
});

<a href="#" onclick="open2(this);">test</a>
```

Comment: It's not reserved, but it does collide with `window.open`.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. To the question poster, the other solutions are probably better - jquery click\bind is ideal and much better than doing it this way.

Comment: this with connection with @RightSaidFred comments works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @mutex: Hope you don't mind, I hijacked your answer just a little.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: no worries, thanks!  clicks before the dom was ready were pretty much why I suggested that jquery bind methods are better.  With the noop I guess it's a non-issue (though I still think using  $().bind\click is a bit cleaner )

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testid').click(function(){
        // more Code here
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="testid">test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your code as is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.button").bind("click", function(){
        alert(this.href);
    });
});

<a href="#" class="button">test</a>
```

Comment: how do I pass two variables to that function then? Just `function(var1, var2)` ?

Comment: @bobek Simple, as such: `$('#foo').bind('click', {msg: message}, function(event) { alert(event.data.msg);});` http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data